# Posting byte array header with Fiddler

Tags: arrays, encoding, http-headers, integration-testing, fiddler

I have developed a `HttpModule` that is supposed to [read `PROXY V2` binary request header](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) and convert it to `'X-Forwarded-For'`

I have been trying to create a request in fiddler that would represent something that looks like [binary PROXY v2 header](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) to do integration testing.

However when I tried adding header decoded from binary

`Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[12] { 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x51, 0x55, 0x49, 0x54, 0x0A })`

> "\r\n\r\n\0\r\nQUIT\n"

and putting output into Fiddler I got 400 error and request didn't even reach my `HttpModule` (breakpoints get hit if I remove invalid header - so no configuration problem here)

[image]

I mean this might not even possible but if it does
**How does one encode data in byte array when sending it with fiddler?**